# Enable/Disable a .NET 4.0 button with jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net

I'm trying to enable a .net LinkButton with jQuery but things have changed a little in .NET 4.0 and simply using attr("disabled", "disabled") or removeAttr("disabled") won't work.

Here is the button.

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButtonContinue" runat="server" Text="Continue" CssClass="button continue" Enabled="false"></asp:LinkButton>
```

This renders out like this:

```
<a class="aspNetDisabled button continue" id="ContentPlaceHolder1_LinkButtonContinue">Continue</a>
```

Note the newly added class of aspNetDisabled.

So I tried this:

```
jQuery(".continue").removeAttr("disabled").removeClass("aspNetDisabled");
```

and this:

```
jQuery(".continue").removeClass("aspNetDisabled");
```

Neither work because there is no disabled attribute to remove so I assume it uses JS to disable it?

How would I go about enabling a button with this class?

Any ideas?

Many thanks

Chris

Comment: try this: $('.continue').attr("disabled", true);

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is, when you have a button like that generated serverside, the page gets some javascript nonsense put onto it, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var theForm = document.forms['aspnetForm'];
if (!theForm) {
    theForm = document.aspnetForm;
}
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
//]]>
</script>
```

And the button will have something like 
`javascript:__doPostBack('id','')` on the href

I think you should try manually defining this href value serverside (or dynamically with javascript on page load, might be easier with the horrible id that gets generated).

In your instance, there is no href so nothing happens even if the anchor is not disabled.

**Edit:**
Would it not just be easier to avoid disabling the button serverside, and disable it with javascript when the page loads?

Comment: I'm working on the assumption that you want to do a postback in which case you need to manually submit the form. You may or may not need to define the javascript to submit this form, depending on if you have any other buttons on your page that are enabled serverside.

Comment: Basically, the page served up by the server has a submit button that is initially disabled. Once the user has successfully completed the section, the button will become enabled and the user can click the button to progress.

Comment: I'd say just enable the button serverside, and disable it client-side when the page loads. Or, as above, make sure your page has href attribute calling the horrible postback method via javascript. That javascript code is automatically added to the page if you have an enabled asp button, but if you don't then you'd need to add it manually in the markup. Make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe that works for you:

```
$('.continue').disabled = false;
```

Another way that can also be used would be:

```
$('.continue').attr("disabled", "");
```

Comment: according to our comments beneath my answer you can see we've already tried this.

Comment: mea culpa for the first snippet, but the second snippet was not mentioned so i thought it could be useful

Answer (score 0):

Using just:

```
$('.continue').removeClass("aspNetDisabled");
```

Should work i guess

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I've tried that but the button remains disabled even when the class is removed.

Comment: I'm also guessing javascript disables the button. Have you tried adding a attribute of enabled="true" or disabled="false"? i don't know if it'll work. Just sharing my thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this..

```
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
    <title></title>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <style type="text/css">
        .disabled-link
        {
            color: Gray;
            cursor: default;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function() {
            var linkButton1 = $('.continue'); // $('#<%= LinkButton1.ClientID %>')
            var href = linkButton1.attr('href');
            $('#<%= EnableButton.ClientID %>').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                linkButton1.attr('href', linkButton1.attr('myCustomAttr')).removeClass('disabled-link');
            });

            $('#<%= DisableButton.ClientID %>').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                linkButton1.attr('href', '#').attr('myCustomAttr', href).addClass('disabled-link');

            });
        });

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server"  CssClass="button continue" PostBackUrl="test.aspx">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
    <br />
    <asp:Button ID="DisableButton" runat="server" Text="Disable" />
    <asp:Button ID="EnableButton" runat="server" Text="Enable" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks but your method requires me to use 2 buttons to do the job of 1. I'm sure there must be a way.

Comment: buttons were  just to show the functionality..you can always use some state variable on client side to toggle the behaviour?